# NSMutableArray addObject doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, arrays

I'm really new to iOS development and I'm trying to create a simple table view, so I added a Table View Controller, added my custom class to it and now I was trying to add items.

So I created a new array:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *activity;
```

And I the viewDidLoad, I tried adding some items to the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
    NSLog(@"Current item: %u", i);
    Item *item = [[Item alloc] init];
    item.time = @"14:30";
    item.text = @"A simple test";
    item.startedAgo = @"yesterday";
    item.project = @"testProject";
    [self.activity addObject:item];
}

NSLog(@"Activity count: %u", [self.activity count]);
```

The log seems to be fine, excpet when I try to output the lenght of the array, it stays 0

> 2012-05-02 14:12:50.772 coop_dev[15352:f803] Current item: 0
>
> ...
>
> 2012-05-02 14:12:50.783 coop_dev[15352:f803] Current item: 19
>
> 2012-05-02 14:12:50.784 coop_dev[15352:f803] Activity count: 0

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you initialize your activity array before adding object to it??
In viewDidLoad initialize your activity array as follows :-

```
self.activity = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
```

Comment: I seem to have forgot that ... activity = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
Now it works fine, thanks a lot. (Will mark it as completed as soon as i can)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you initialise your array before using it

```
self.activity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If your using ARC there is no need for autorelease.